# Tailwind css phone number input hide border left and right

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

i am trying to create a react component that picks a country code and phone number. I am having a challenge, hiding the border left of the country code select and border right of the phone number input so that they can appear like this :

Expected input :
[image: expected]

For now, this is how my input looks :
[image: current input]

```
export default function PhoneNumberInput({
  name,
  country_name,
  value,
  country_value,
  className,
  autoComplete,
  placeholder,
  country_name_placeHolder,
  required,
  isFocused,
  handleChange,
  error,
  options = [],
}) {
  const input = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
      if (isFocused) {
          input.current.focus();
      }
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-start">
          <div className="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm w-full flex justify-between">
              <select
                  name={country_name}
                  value={country_value}
                  id={country_name}
                  className={
                      `shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 px-4 rounded-full ${
                          error && "border-red-300"
                      } ` + className
                  }
                  ref={input}
                  required={required}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              >
                  {options.map((item) => (
                      <option
                          key={item.id ?? item.value}
                          value={item.id || item.value}
                      >
                          {item.name || item.label}
                      </option>
                  ))}
              </select>
              {error && (
                  <div className="mt-1 ml-4 text-red-600 text-sm">
                      {error}
                  </div>
              )}

              <input
                  type={"text"}
                  name={name}
                  value={value}
                  className={
                      `shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 px-4 rounded-full ${
                          error && "border-red-300"
                      } ` + className
                  }
                  ref={input}
                  autoComplete={autoComplete}
                  required={required}
                  placeholder={placeholder}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              />
          </div>
          {error && (
              <div className="mt-1 ml-4 text-red-600 text-sm">{error}</div>
          )}
      </div>
  );
}
```

Any advise or useful links on how to hide the borders on the edges will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving a `border` and `rounded` to each element inside the PhoneNumber component, you can provide `rounded-full` and `border-gray-300` only to their parent element.

This way, both of your elements will be wrapped in one rounded border.

Then, you could add the border element in the middle in many ways; here are two possible solutions:

1. Give the element on the left `border-r-n` / the element on the right `border-l-n` (n should equal your desired size).
2. Create another element between your existing elements and give it a border of `border-[1px]`.

Here's a Tailwind Play example I created: https://play.tailwindcss.com/rBZj1Dvaww